# Convert a lines of list into dictionary which is having key and value in it

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists which have two values in them. I want to convert those two lists into a dictionary, where the first value in a list should be the key and second value should be value.

e.g:

```
list1=[a,1]
list2=[b,2]
```

should result in

```
dict={a:1,b:2}
```

Comment: Do you mean `list1 = ['a', 1]; list2 = ['b', 2]`? It has a different meaning if you leave the quote marks off `a` and `b`, since then `a` and `b` are variables.

Answer (score 6):

This will do:

```
dict([list1, list2])
```

Or something more verbose and easier to understand but less general:

```
{list1[0]: list1[1], list2[0]: list2[1]}
```

Comment: if i print that means I am getting {a: b, 1: 2} like this but i should get {a:1,b:2}

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> list1=['a',1]
>>> list2=['b',2]
>>> dict={}
>>> dict[list1[0]]= list1[1]
>>> dict[list2[0]]= list2[1]
```

You should read the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) for more information and why this work.